# Why is my component not effectively receiving props?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I keep getting a message that the item I'm trying to access via props is undefined. Can you please tell me why it's not working?

Here is where the instance where the props are attempting to be passed... I'm specifically talking about the tellus and yourTrial props.

```
import React from 'react'
import Info from './components/Info'
import Upsell from '../../../general/components/order/components/Upsell'
import FormTwo from '../../../general/components/forms/FormTwo'
import Footer from '../../../cbd-desktop/components/layout/Footer'


export default class Order extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
      <div>
    <div style={styles.header}>
      <img style={styles.leaf} src="./resources/desktop-img/leaves_top.png" />
      <img style={styles.logo} src="./resources/desktop-img/logo_white.png" />
    </div>
    <div style={styles.wrapper}>
      <div style={styles.leftWrapper}>
        <Info />
        <Upsell styles={upsellStyles} />
      </div>
        <FormTwo styles={formStyles} tellus="Tell us where to send" yourTrial="YOUR TRIAL BOTTLE"} />
      </div>
  </div>
  <Footer style={styles.footer}/>
</div>
)
 }
}
```

And here is where I am trying to display these values on the child... towards the top in two h2s

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { stepTwoSubmit, saveBillingData } from 
'../../actions/formStepTwoActions'
import { addReceiptProduct } from '../../actions/receiptActions'
import FormTwoInputs from './components/FormTwoInputsComponent.jsx'
import Throbber from '../throbber/Throbber'
import FormWarning from './components/FormWarningComponent.jsx'
import Button from '../../../cbd-desktop/components/layout/Button'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  state:state,
  config:state.config,
  downsellProduct:state.downsell.downsellProduct || {},
  receiptProducts:state.receipt.receiptProducts || []
})
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  stepTwoSubmit,
  saveBillingData,
  addReceiptProduct
}

@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export default class FormTwo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)


  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    let formTwoResponse = nextProps.state.stepTwo.formTwoResponse

    this.checkOrderStatus(formTwoResponse)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fillMainOrder()
    this.calculateViewers()
    this.calculateTimer()
  }


  render() {
    let { state, props, inputs, onInputFocus, saveInputVal, styles } = this,
         CustomTag = props.labels ? 'label' : 'span',
        { submitting, formWarning } = state,
        { invalidInputID, text, visible } = formWarning


     return (
      <div style={styles.formWrapper}>
        <p style={styles.yellowBanner}>{this.state.viewers} people viewing this product right now</p>
          <div style={styles.formInnerWrapper}>
            <div style={styles.headerWrapper}>
              <h2 style={styles.header}>{this.props.tellus}</h2>
              <h2 style={styles.header}>{this.props.yourTrial}</h2>
           </div>
            <div style={styles.weAccept}>
              <p style={styles.weAcceptText}>We Accept:</p>
               <img style ={styles.cardImage} src="resources/desktop-img/cards.png" />
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
              <FormTwoInputs onInputFocus={onInputFocus} saveInputVal={saveInputVal} CustomTag={CustomTag} styles={styles} />

              <FormWarning visible={visible} invalidInputID={invalidInputID} text={text} />
              <Button style={styles.button} buttonText="RUSH MY TRIAL" />
            </form>
          </div>
           <img src="resources/desktop-img/secure.png" />
            <div style={styles.urgencyWrapper}>
              <div style={styles.urgencyTextWrapper}>
                <span style={styles.redText}>{this.state.viewers} people are viewing this offer right now -</span>
                <span style={styles.blueText}>{this.state.counter}</span>
              </div>
              <p style={styles.blueText}>Claim Your Bottle Now</p>
           </div>
        <Throbber throbberText='Confirming your shipment...' showThrobber={submitting} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: instead of this.props.tellus, try using props.tellus

Comment: you are missing a closing brace to end your class constructor function for formTwo, not sure if that is why there is the unexpected behavior.  It seems like everything looks right, hard to debug without a working version